# what is this on my cowpea leaves?

Tags: diseases

Found this on my cowpeas. Looks like some kind of infection splashed onto the leaves, so bacterial or fungal probably.

Any ideas? My best guess so far is Cercospora.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: @Bamboo I'm in Arkansas, US.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a fungal or bacterial infection, but more like insect damage. It might well be caterpillars, possibly Bean Leaf Roller - in the top picture, the edge of the top middle leaf is folded or rolled over in one spot, and that could mean a caterpillar of some variety has used it to protect itself. The other damage looks like areas that have been grazed or nibbled which would be typical of caterpillars, but if this is the cause, it doesn't seem to be a major problem, unless it's got a lot worse since you took the pics. Inspect closely to see if you can find anything, and pull back that little folded over bit of leaf to see if there's still anything in there. Further info here https://www.growingproduce.com/vegetables/beware-of-bean-leafroller-in-your-legume-crops/